# PHP simple csv export is not work with array in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, csv

I'm tring to export `csv` file from the PHP array in wordpress plugin.

However when I put `die` inside the `foreach` the CSV file  created with the first elements of array. otherwise `CSV` file not generate.

Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => test name 1
            [lname] => lname 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fname] => test name 2
            [lname] => lname
        )
)
```

Code :

```
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=loyalty.csv');

    $filename = "loyalty.csv";
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($handle,  array('First Name','last Name'));
    foreach($loUsers as $row) {
        fputcsv($handle, $row);
    //die;
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

When the `die` is not commenting nothing will happen but if I put but csv file created with first element.
Seems the code is correct and can't find the issue.
Thanks

Comment: put header after you are done with file writing

Comment: @MichalHainc Tried the try catch but nothing there

Comment: @MichalHainc yes. The code is working and and I tried in phpfiddle. However it is not working on my wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=User_Sample.csv");
        // Disable caching
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
        header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

        $data = array(
            array('User Type', 'User Name', 'Category', 'Mobile Number'),
            array('I', 'Anuj Kumar', 'Building Construction', '8500000001'),
            array('I', 'Arvind Kumar', 'Carpentary', '8500000002'),
            array('I', 'Mridul Ohja', 'Civil Engineering', '8500000003'),
            array('I', 'Naman Kumar', 'Electrical', '8500000004'),
            array('I', 'Sumati', 'Faucets', '8500000005'),
            array('I', 'Anjum', 'Flooring Tiles / Marbles', '8500000006'),
            array('I', 'Rajat', 'Painting', '8500000007'),
            array('C', 'Arvind', 'Plumbing', '8500000008'),
            array('C', 'Rohit', 'Sanitaryware', '8500000009'),
            array('C', 'Gaurav', 'Soil Test Analyst', '8500000010')
        );

        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            fputcsv($output, $row); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
        }
        fclose($output);
```

It works for me.

Comment: I just copy your code try but same issue there and when put a die it generate the csv with one row

Answer (score 1):

Check this out its easy:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('includes/config.php');
    $filename = "testing-exports.csv";
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $insquery = "SELECT username FROM r_institution where status=1";
    //$exportstmt = $conn->query($insquery);
    $insresults = $conn->query($insquery);
    //$insresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exportstmt);
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $content = array();
    $title = array("Institution Emails");
    foreach ($insresults as $rs) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = stripslashes($rs["username"]);
        $content[] = $row;
    }
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, $title);
    foreach ($content as $con) {
        fputcsv($output, $con);
    }
?>
```